# Volley NetworkImageView with default image instead of default image resource id

Tags: android, svg, android-volley, networkimageview

I am using Google Volley NetworkImageView with great success. I am also in the process of switching various images over to SVG via android-svg. I would like to use some of the svg converted images as the default image for NetworkImageView but it only supports setDefaultImageResId() and not a setDefaultImage().

Looking in the actual source code it appears extending the class is not a good option as the loadImageIfNecessary method has an inner class of ImageContainer that references mDefaultImageId and the setDefaultImageOrNull method which also references that variable is private.

Really don't want to switch to another library unless that is the only way around this.

Is there an existing extension that supports more than setDefaultImageResId? If not is there a recommended replacement library that is reasonably easy to swap out that does support this functionality?

Comment: So what you asking is, change the default image that is shown before downloading the actual image?

Comment: Yes, I want the default image that is shown before the URL image is ready to be something other than an Android resource ID. I want to use an in memory image that I create from an SVG object.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a FrameLayout and overlay the default image and loaded image on top of one another.

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_height">

    <SVGImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  ...etc.../>
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                  android:id="@+id/photo"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The default SVG image will show until the photo gets loaded by Volley.  Then you can either leave the default image there, or hide it with `setVisibility()`.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code, all of the variable you need to set the `ImageView` a bitmap is private. So here is your options:

1.Change the source code, I suggest strongly don't.

2.Use the Reflection API. I wouldn't,

3.Come on there is 2 major alternative library out there that can do what you want to do, and actually they have built it just for downloading image over the Internet, and they have done that great. Volley mostly is used for RESTful communication. Here are the alternative libraries [UniversalImageDownloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

These libraries load images to your already defined `ImageView`s so you can call `imageView.setBitmap(bitmap)`. That's it